# What's a good method for filtering out glitches from stepper motor step signal?

Tags: stepper-motor, esd, emi-filtering

I have a product which contains 2 stepper motors. I've been hardening the system against EMI and ESD.

It used to reset or crash when hit with static. I've been able to mostly eliminate this by grounding everything that's metal, shielding, adding ferrites, etc.

One problem I have *not* been able to eliminate, is that when the machine is statically shocked, the stepper motors will almost always move one step.

The step signals originate in a MCU on one PCB, travel through a ~12in ribbon, and end at 2 stepper drivers. I believe that EMI is coupling into the long wires and causing an erroneous pulse.

**There is currently no termination or filtering on the step line, I would like to add some. What's a good strategy for this?**

Here are some ideas I have:

- Add a RC low pass filter near the stepper drivers.
- Add a small cap ~1nF to ground near the drivers to shunt high frequency noise to ground.
- Add a resistor to ground near the drivers such that a few milliamps are required for the step signal to go high.

I'm using a barbecue lighter as a static wand for testing.

**Edit:** I've added 10nF caps right at the stepper drivers, and that seemed to dramatically reduce the problem. Should I be worried about the capacitive load stressing out the MCU?

Comment: Is your stepper driver ground directly coupled to chassis/earth ground?

Comment: @regimon Yes, the chassis ground is connected to the circuit ground at one point, where the barrel jack connector comes into the product. The incoming negative from the power supply is earthed, unless the customer pulls the ground pin off or something.

Comment: perhaps the step signal needs to be differential ... step only when one line is high and the second line is low