# Why Does a Shunt Cap Help For Deglitching Digital Signals?

Tags: rf, noise, emi-filtering

In some of my projects I have digital pulse signals that are sent over fairly long wires (~12in). For example tachometer readings or stepper signals.

I've tried various things to reduce glitches in these signals (for example causing erroneous stepper motor steps). I've determined experimentally that adding a small shunt capacitor ~1nF near the receive end of the signal dramatically reduces the glitches in almost every case.

**What I'm wondering is why that is?** My naive understanding is that very short, sharp RF pulses are shunted to ground through the cap. However the shunt cap seems to be much more effective than a low pass filter, so I assume there's more to it than that. For example maybe the cap is spoiling the wires ability to function as an antenna?

Related question I asked about a year ago: [What's a good method for filtering out glitches from stepper motor step signal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496364/whats-a-good-method-for-filtering-out-glitches-from-stepper-motor-step-signal)

**Edit:** Here's a diagram of what I mean by "shunt capacitor"
[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: How have you connected this capacitor? "However the shunt cap seems to be much more effective than a low pass filter" Is the shunt cap in some way *not* a low pass filter?  Did you put it in series?

Comment: @KH Diagram added. It does act as a low pass filter if you count the impedance of the line, but if that described it completely then adding a series resistor to make a classic RC lowpass should strengthen the de-glitching effect, not weaken it.

Comment: Frankly I'm not good at filtering type stuff, but in simplest form, a capacitor resists change in voltage by storing energy and releasing it back into the circuit.  If a pulse is short enough(high enough frequency), it has enough energy to charge the capacitor less, so low speed pulses that have time to charge the capacitor get through while high frequency pulses will make a little bumpy bump but not a recognisable change of state.  Seems like the definition of a low pass filter with just a capacitor, although I know without some resistance, it could ring with whatever inductance is present.

Comment: What is the power supply arrangement? Does the motor current use the same ground path as the logic signal?

Comment: @Transistor No it doesn't. The glitches usually occur due to static shocks.

Comment: @Drew You're adding new information please clarify what exactly you mean by glitches and what causes them.

Comment: @DKNguyen Please refer to my old question for details of the specific problem I was having. This question is about the solution I've been using since then. It does work, I've tested it extensively on several designs, I'm wondering why.

Comment: Are you using STP wire for signals? Are they balanced? then use a balun or shunt them with caps causing heat rise in drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a signal line, not a power line, you are asking about right?

The resistor does strengthen the effect, however, it is possible to have too much of a good thing. The RC filter is not smart enough to discriminate between transitions due to noise and transitions due to your signal.

In this case, it is probably slowing down the edge which reduces transmission line effects such as ringing, undershoot, and overshoot. However, the stepper driver's input requires a sufficiently fast transition to minimize the time spent in the ambiguous region between logic HI and logic LO, in order to operate properly. If you lowpass filter too much, it begins to deglitch even good edges which causes the transition slow down too much and spend too much in the ambiguous logic region which then confuses the stepper driver.

The same thing can be achieved by removing the 1nF cap with a series resistor. This method utilizes the inherent input capacitance of the stepper driver inputs, whereas your "deglitching cap" method utilizes the inherent output resistance of the driver and line.

As far as slowing the edge to reduce transmission line effects, low R with large C achieves the same lowpass filtering as High R with low C.

**ADDITION SINCE OP IS ASKING ABOUT SPORADIC GLITCHES CAUSED BY NEARBY STATIC:**

However, if the issue is induced noise, the shunt capacitor is more resistant to induced noise than the series resistor precisely because it requires the line to be driven harder to register a change in the signal. However, it does not discriminate and both noise sources and the driver must work harder. I would expect a series resistor to do nothing against induced noise.

In your testing, you say it behaves worse with a resistor and capacitor than with just a capacitor. I think this is probably because the resistor provides some isolation between the input and the driver. In essence, it weakens strength at which the driver holds the input at a particular voltage level which makes it easier for induced noise to cause changes.

Have you tried something like placing a Schmitt trigger at the stepper input with no capacitor or resistor?

Comment: The glitches don't occur constantly only sporadically, for example due to a static shock. This leads me to believe that it's induced noise, rather than a transmission line issue.

Comment: @Drew What kind of static shocks and where?

Comment: I'll see if I can test series resistor vs no series resistor and report back. If I remember my testing correctly, the series resistor made things worse but I'll test that.

Comment: I have a bbq lighter on which I've grounded the shaft which I use for simulating static. If I lay the ground wire over the machine and then apply a spark to a nearby outlet cover a glitch will occur, without any electrical path through the machine. Shocking the machine directly causes a similar effect. It used to also crash display, but I've been able to eliminate that with improved grounding.

Comment: Based on what your saying the shunt cap is simply "making the line harder to drive", which makes it less susceptible to induced noise. Assuming I have that right, that's the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: @Drew That is what I am saying. You should be able to see something similar with shunt resistors to GND as well. It artificially lowers the input impedance which makes it more difficult to drive and basically forces the driver to provide more current for the same signal level which makes noise have to provide more current to override it. Not as power efficient though. Try experimenting with a resistance that would require 5mA or so (or whatever your MCU pin can safely source) at your logic HI voltage levels .

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.